# Battery/Power icon missing

Tags: windows-7

Ok this has been over a month now, my battery icon is missing. I am using a laptop `HP Pavilion DV6` with `Windows 7 64-bit`. This seems a common problem when you search on Google but I have tried many things and did not come up to a solution yet. Battery is sometimes charging (red light) and sometimes just the power light appears (blue light) but the I can never check the actual status of battery.

And yes, this is not just the show/hide icon problem. When I go to properties where I can show/hide system icons, Power icon dropdown is disabled there.

These are the solutions I have tried:

```
1. Click on the start button
2. Go to the SEARCH box on the bottom and search under "Device". There you will see several options showing up. Click on "Device Manager". 
3. Click on the "+" of System Devices. 
4. There you will find something like "ACPI Fixed Tools" or something like that. It's the first one from the list. 
5. Right click the ACPI and select "Uninstall". 
6. Restart your computer. The ACPI will be automatically reinstalled. 
7. Once your computer is restarted, click on the arrow button on the toolbar (lower right on the screen).
8. Select "Properties" and there you will see that your power icon has been activated so simply select "power" under system icons. 
9. Now your power icon will appear.
```

Also tried this FIX proviede by Microsoft: `http://support.microsoft.com/kb/945011#FixItForMe`

Tried this as well: `http://www.askvg.com/how-to-change-windows-update-settings-when-managed-or-disabled-by-system-administrator/`

And many such options as well. Now I am tired a lot, and will appreciate if someone can post a genuine answer here.

[image]

Comment: [Fix for “system icons grayed out in Windows 7″](http://karl.kranich.org/2011/04/18/fix-for-system-icons-grayed-out-in-windows-7/)

Comment: Didn't work @DavidPostill

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The screenshot tells you the answer.

The yellow sign at the top states that some settings have been altered due to a system policy being affected. You have to enable the policy causing this behavior.

Go to start, and type in the search bar: Edit group policy

From there navigate to `User Configuration` -> `Administrative Template` -> `Start Menu and Taskbar`.

In this list, find `Remove the battery meter`. Its probably enabled/yes. Change it to Disabled or Not Configured.

Comment: You're welcome. :) Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to drop the answer that solved this problem for me (I have the exact same laptop as the original poster as well...)

[image: Steps to restore battery icon]

Source: https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001560.htm